# Going from ng-app to a manual bootstrap is not working, getting blank page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In order to run hybrid angular 1 and angular 2, I am following these guidelines: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade

One issue I have run into is switching from using ng-app to bootstrap to a manual bootstrap method as manual bootstrap is required from the upgrade to work.  The below ng-app bootstrapping method works just fine:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html ng-app="c2c" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>c2c</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prompt:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,300,400,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

  <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body ng-controller="UserController as mainApp">
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="c2c-header"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-if="emailClass!='email'">
      <div class="c2c-navbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!--<div ng-if="emailClass!='email'" class="talent-aside col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2" ng-if="mainApp.hasPermission('DealPoint.VIEW')"></div>-->
      <div class="talent-aside col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="talent-content body-bg col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
        <div class="ui-view"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  <div class="pageloader" ng-if="loader">
    <img src="app\assets\images\balls.gif" width="100" height="100" class="loaderImage" />
    <span class="loaderText" ng-if="loadingText.length>0">{{loadingText}}</span>
    </div>
    -->


  <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!--<script src="../bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>-->

  <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
  <!-- endinject -->

  <!-- inject:partials -->
  <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->



</body>

</html>
```

But when I switch to the manual bootstrapping method, I get a blank page with no console errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>c2c</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prompt:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,300,400,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

  <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body ng-controller="UserController as mainApp">
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="c2c-header"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-if="emailClass!='email'">
      <div class="c2c-navbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!--<div ng-if="emailClass!='email'" class="talent-aside col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2" ng-if="mainApp.hasPermission('DealPoint.VIEW')"></div>-->
      <div class="talent-aside col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="talent-content body-bg col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
        <div class="ui-view"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  <div class="pageloader" ng-if="loader">
    <img src="app\assets\images\balls.gif" width="100" height="100" class="loaderImage" />
    <span class="loaderText" ng-if="loadingText.length>0">{{loadingText}}</span>
    </div>
    -->


  <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!--<script src="../bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>-->

  <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
  <!-- endinject -->

  <!-- inject:partials -->
  <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
<script>
    angular.module('c2c', [])
      .controller('UserController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greetMe = 'World';
      }]);

    angular.element(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['c2c']);
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the document to be ready to bootstrap AngularJS.

Change

```
 angular.element(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['c2c']);
 });
```

To

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function(){
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['c2c']);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.element(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['c2c']);
    });
```

The anonymous function here is not returning anything; in fact, I don't believe you need the angular.element wrapper either.  Try just using

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['c2c']);
```